# Javascript Array not working in IE7 and older versions but working in IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

Javascript Array not working in IE7 and older versions but working in IE10
Here is my code which is working in IE10 but not working in IE7.

```
    number = "123";
    var j=0;
    alert(number[j]);
```

Result in IE7

> **undefined**

Result in IE10

> **1**

Please let me know how to call the variable values as single dimension array in older browsers.

Comment: Your code will alert `undefined` in any browser, even in IE10. Are you sure you don't have `number='123';`?

Comment: perhaps alert(String(number)[j]);

Comment: Its string.. not number.. corrected the question..

Comment: @EvanTrimboli : I have not copied it.. i tried myself and worked fine in IE10... and found that its not working in IE7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Javascript Array not working in IE7

This is not an *array* “not working” – you have a *string* value here (the browser will convert it to one, because for numbers no such kind of access is defined), and are trying to access it’s single characters with a zero-based index.

Older IE simply don’t support this – so cast it to a string (implicitly/explicitly) and then use the [`charAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) method of the String object instead .

Answer (score 0):

`(''+number)[j]` should work in any browser, assuming that `number` is something that can be coerced to a `String` anyway.